# how send request from android form to localhost URL???

Tags: java

i want to send android form data to specific URL (like login.php page "this is a page of my website that will verification of form data from DB saved record")

Answer (score 1):

See this tutorial and you are done

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

You actually need two Classes to do this 
 1. Your Activity
 2. JSON Parser

Here is the sample code for two of them, you can modify it as per your own needs

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    static JSONArray jArr = null;

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET method
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }          

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "utf-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());

        }
        Log.i("PHP Error", "["+json+"]");
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.getMessage() + json);
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }

    public JSONArray getAllMessages(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }          

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "utf-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());

        }
        Log.i("PHP Error", "["+json+"]");
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jArr = new JSONArray(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.getMessage() + json);
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jArr;

    }
}
```

Activity

```
public class Home extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    String message;

    private static String url_addmessage = "http://www.yourdomain.com/addmessage.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        final EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                        message = et.getText().toString();

                        Log.i("message to be posted", message);

                        new RegisterMe().execute();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("Exception while getting Message", e.getMessage().toString());
                }

                }
        });

        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(Home.this, GetMessage.class));
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    class RegisterMe extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        String Message=null;

        public boolean workdone(String Message){

            boolean x=false;
            if(Message == "Done"){
                x=true;
            }
            return x;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Home.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Transaction In Progress... \n You Have The Right To Remain \n Silent & Patient :)");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", message));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_addmessage, "GET", params);

            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            try{
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if(success == 1){
                    Message = "Done";
                    Log.d("Work Done", "Message Added");
                }
                else{

                    Log.d("Work Done", "Message Not Added");
                }
            } catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if(new RegisterMe().workdone(Message)){
                Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Message Added Successfully.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Sorry There was some error in processing your request, please try after some time.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }
    }

}
```